# Show hidden folder in save dialog

Tags: hidden-files, dialog

I would like to extract some `.ttf` files into my `~/.local/share/fonts` folder directly from the save dialog. However, the hidden files are not shown in the dialog.

Is there a way to manually enter a path or somehow switch on the hidden files in these kinds of dialogs? I'm on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It was actually really simple: pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> when in the dialogue box toggles the appearance of hidden files and folders.

Comment: That is the fastest way. Also right-clicking allows to change the setting.